# AWS Elasticache for Redis Replication

Tags: redis, replication, amazon-elasticache

In my AWS Redis Elasticache cluster(Cluster mode disabled) `INFO REPLICATION` command in the primary shows different IP than the replica node IPs in `slave<n>:ip=<IP>` section. Those IPs don't even belong to the VPC I am working on.

For RDS AWS clearly stated that they use the engine's native replication mechanism [here](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/read-replicas/#:%7E:text=It%20then%20uses%20the%20engines%27%20native%20asynchronous%20replication%20to%20update%20the%20read%20replica%20whenever%20there%20is%20a%20change%20to%20the%20source%20DB%20instance). For Redis replication they didn't clearly [exposed](https://Asynchronous%20replication%20mechanisms%20are%20used%20to%20keep%20the%20read%20replicas%20synchronized%20with%20the%20primary) what kind of replication they use.

We need those replica IPs/node endpoints for our inventory and monitoring but those values are completely irrelevant and don't understand how those stuffs work under the hood.

**Can somebody help me out with relevant explanation?**